# Manipulando uma nova guia com playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, navegador-de-internet, chromium

Já li vários tópicos da documentação do playwright, mas ainda não descobri como faço para manipular uma nova guia durante o scrap de dados. Eu já sei como criar uma nova tab e manipular ela, mas para isso eu passo uma url para criar essa tab, e o scrap que estou fazendo é tipo um botão que sempre que clico me leva para um site diferente em uma nova tab, aí queria saber como posso fazer para passar a manusear essa nova tab que abriu ao invés d continuar na antiga.

```
for itemId in range(250):
    itemId+=1
    # conferindo se os itens percorridos existem, se sim procede, se não cancela a ação
    if page.locator(("text='{}'".format('%03d' % itemId))):
        page.click("text='{}'".format('%03d' % itemId))
        page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
        page.locator('a[target="_blank"]').click() #parte onde eu queria que passasse a usar a nova guia que abriu ao clicar no botao
        print(page.locator("div[ng-repeat='(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid']".format(itemId)).all_text_contents())
        page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Para quem esta com o mesmo problema que o meu, consegui achar uma resposta no site gringo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993712/how-to-handle-multiple-pages-with-playwright-python Neste link tem uma solução que pode ajudar!